# Domain Name Registration via Microsoft?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, microsoft, azure

Is it possible to get Domain Name Registration services through Microsoft?  I am currently using two well-known companies for two different domains and I am not happy with either of them.  One of the companies is a Shared Hosting provider.  The other company was at one time the leading Domain Name Registrar in the industry.

The first company is cheap and inexpensive, but their security is light and I will be ending my service with that company in favor of a low cost Windows Azure plan.   The second company has good security but it charges too much for something as trivial as Domain Name Registration.

BTW: I don’t know if it matters, but my domain name is of the format
 www.[someNotRealAndBogusDomainName].net

Comment: Why do you think that Microsoft would be better if they do offer Domain Name Registration?

Comment: You mention _Windows Azure_, are you talking about more than simply domain name registration?

Comment: @Pettit - a) Microsoft ecommerce and business sites allow special characters in the password and quick access via LiveId/Windows 8  b) Microsoft is careful about what info it sends in plain text email    c) I trust Microsoft with my credit card number   d) I suppose Microsoft would renew my domain name for me automatically if they could not contact me  e) Microsoft "usually" exhibits corporate social responsibility; however, I do disagree with Microsoft on some issues such as what defines a marriage...

Comment: @w3d - I am just talking about Domain Name Registration.  I only mentioned Azure because I am very happy with it and was wondering if there was some Azure setting that would allow me to register my domain name.  The security with Azure seems very impressive to me.  I figured if Azure security could be as high as it is, then surely anything else Microsoft can offer would have the same quality of security.

Comment: Have you looked in to this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain

Answer (score 3):

You can purchase a domain direct from  azure try to view this link. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

Success

Comment: Worth mentioning that domain registrations are available in the Azure Portal via a partnership between Microsoft and GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

While Microsoft is a registrar i'm not sure they offer domain name registration services to the public. They do list ASP hosting services here http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home it's not MS hosting or registering domain names.

Comment: Good point, but I think Windows Azure is the ideal web host for hobbyists like myself.  I'm still in a trial plan but it looks like I can get: top notch security; lots of storage space; 100MB Azure SQL database; and reasonable bandwidth for about $25 a month.  Before, I was able to use other web hosting providers but I always felt afraid that they would do something bad with any data I might collect.  There are much cheaper hosting providers, but I wouldn't dare use them for a site that may collect/store user information because the cheap ones I've tried have serious security issues...

Comment: Actually, to be honest, if I do complete my migration to Windows Azure, I won't technically need a domain name anymore since the base URL that Azure gave my website is already fairly human readable.  I can just go back to using a live.com style email address and continue to use the http://*.cloudapp.net/   URL that Microsoft gave me.  I guess Domain Name Registration would just be a nicety in my case.  I just find it odd that Microsoft doesn't offer to register domain names for their Azure customers.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, on azure portal, there's a new buy domain in preview mode, but I cannot find any documentation and this is really new, so this may be comming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not provide domain name system but you can buy web hosting services from Microsoft. There are many types of web hosting plans available at Microsoft. You have to just visit the link given by Anagio.

Comment: I think most of those services are by third parties.  I understand that many of those third parties have gold partnerships with Microsoft but they don't seem to have the same level of security that Windows Azure does.  In particular, the two hosting providers I used to use are listed on that list but I feel they both have major security issues.  In fact, I think one of the two providers is supposedly a Microsoft Gold Certified hosting provider!?  How is it that a Microsoft Gold Certified hosting provider can have serious security flaws?????

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of domain registrars recommended by Microsoft's own Office 365 team:

- Go Daddy
- Melbourne IT
- Network Solutions
- Hover
- eNom Central
- 1&1 Internet
- Register.com

([Source](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/En-ca/office365-enterprises/ff637616.aspx#bkmk_purchase))

Comment: Microsoft is not recommending them. They are listed only as "some common domain registrars".

Comment: Avoid Melbourne IT like a plague - they are expensive and very poor service. I had a domain registered with Yahoo which they transferred to Melbourne IT. Melbourne IT started changing $35/year for domain. When I tried to transfer to a diff registrar it took them more than 7 days to do so.

Comment: Avoid register.com (details on demand). Google Domains is now a good alternative. Also gandi.net has positive reviews.

Comment: @DharmendarKumar'DK' I had the similar bad experience with Melbourne IT as user `@DharmendarKumar'DK'`. I would also suggest avoiding them.